# How to set permission in sys_create

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, system-calls

In linux I want to use sys_create to create a simple abc.txt file, but when I set the permission, the output file gets a wrong permission.

Here is my code:

```
Section   .text
global _start

_start:
mov eax, 8
jmp short GoToCall
shellcode:
pop ebx
mov ecx, 544
int 0x80

mov ebx,0
mov eax,1
int 0x80


GoToCall:
call shellcode
db 'abc.txt',0
```

When I execute the above code, abc.txt gets this permission:

```
----r---T
```

I dont want to use flags or etc because I want to use this assembly code as a shellcode.

Answer (score 0):

`544` is in decimal. I assume you wanted it in octal, so either convert it to decimal or use the format appropriate for your assembler. Unfortunately you forgot to mention which one you use, but for example in `nasm` you can write `544o` to get `-r-xr--r--` (you also forgot to mention what permissions you wanted to set).